# Sharing data through multiple environments (dev/test/stage/prod) for one usecase

Tags: design, architecture, database

I am looking for a concept that handles the needs of some data to be distributed in several environments (lets say we have dev, test, stage and prod).

Example:

We are setting up planned outages of banks we are using and share that information through REST API with our clients. Now banks basically do not provide sandbox/dev environments (its just some mock versions and its VERY different to real use-cases) while clients need to test it even on sandbox. Therefore sandbox and prod are both connected to real banks. As clients are using sandbox for testing a lot of things, they should know about outages there as well. At this moment we have to fill it twice - on sandbox and on prod environment.

How to update same information to both (or somehow propagate data, it does not have to be same instantly) - to Sandbox and Prod - while keep those environments as separated as possible?